# Select empty columns and drop them in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

This may be an easy process, but has been confusing me. Let's say I have the following df:

```
import pandas as pd
  
# creating a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' :['A', 'B', 'B', 'C'], 
                   'col2' :['B', 'A', 'B', 'H'],
                   'col3' :['', '', '', ''],
                   'val' :['','','','']})
print(df)
 col1 col2 col3 val
0    A    B         
1    B    A         
2    B    B         
3    C    H
```

Now I wanna identify empty columns and drop them. Here is what I am doing:

```
empty_cols = [col for col in df if df[col].isnull().all()]
print(empty_cols)
[]
False
```

which returns [] and False. Am I making a mistake somewhere here? Thanks!

Comment: you dont have nulls, you have a blank space, try `df.loc[:,~df.eq("").all()]`

Comment: The way you are creating the columns they are not empty, they contain ```''```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this

```
empty = []
for col in df.columns:
  if df[col].sum() == "":
    empty.append(col)
```

Alternatively like this, if you want a one liner:

```
empty = [col for col in df if df[col].sum() == ""]
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you need to check `''` instead of `isnull()`, because, null is None in Python, but you have just empty stings, so they are not None.

P.S my code to detect and drop.

```
empty = [df[col].name for col in df if not df[col].all()]
df = df.drop(empty, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If by "empty" you mean and string with no charatchers like '', then you can chek for that instead of null values

```
empty_cols = [col for col in df if df[col].str.contains('').all()]
```